# Write Json elements in correct hierarchy

Tags: c#, json

I have a program that first reads certain parts from a json like instruction.
Get the zipcode, get the housenumber.
Then I write the json to a file. First I wrote the json result like this:

```
{
   "company":[
      {
         "timestamp":"6/6/2021 8:32:55 AM",
         "registrationdate":"5/6/2021 09:03:13 AM",
         "address":{
            "coAdressenavn":""
         },
         "address":{
            "addressnumber":{
               "cityarea":""
            }
         },
         "address":{
            "addressnumber":{
               "housenumber":""
            }
         },
         "address":{
            "addressnumber":{
               "citysection":""
            }
         },
         "address":{
            "area":{
               "zipnumber":""
            }
         },
         "address":{
            "area":{
               "cityname":""
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The people I send the json too said I had to have it in this format:

```
{
   "company":[
      {
         "timestamp":"6/6/2021 8:32:55 AM",
         "registrationdate":"5/6/2021 09:03:13 AM",
         "address":{
            "coAdressenavn":"",
            "addressnumber":{
               "cityarea":"",
               "housenumber":"",
               "citysection":""
            },
            "area":{
               "zipnumber":"",
               "cityname":""
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I store and the write the json in a hierarchy to achived this?
As you see it is not only parent/child, but the hierarchy goes deeper than that.

Comment: Are they *really* expecting JSON with duplicate property names? RFC-7159 *specifically* discourages that: An object whose names are all unique is interoperable in the sense that all software implementations receiving that object will agree on the name-value mappings.  When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs, including duplicates.

Comment: Note that it would be a lot easier to read both of your JSON files if you would run them through a formatter so we can see the structure in a more idiomatic way.

Comment: the formatting of the JSON - the way it looks is really the responsibility of the reader. if you include the formatting it just bulks out the file.
What software are they using to view the file?

Comment: Try `Newtonsoft.Json` to read the file into c# objects. You can use https://app.quicktype.io to get the C# models from your sample JSON.

Comment: I think the question is really about the structure of the JSON and ___not___ the format.

Comment: I wrote wrong Json for how the output should be and now I have corrected it. I have also used a Json formatter.